# CoreNLP local Server crashes with relations (kbp) annotator

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have downloaded CoreNLP server 3.6.0 from [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html) and followed [these instruction](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html).

Although it works on [corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run/), when going to `localhost:9000` and choosing the `relations` annotator, the server crashes with:

> edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/supervised.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL

Having searched online, `supervised.ser.gz` is nowhere to be found. Google returns 1 hit - the actual github file where the error above is declared.

What steps does one need to take to have `kbp` working on a local server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading and compiling the GitHub version of the code, along with the most recent models file. Neither Wikidict nor the KBP relation annotators are in CoreNLP 3.6.0. KBP should work fine with the most recent models jar, but if you want to use the WikiDict models, be sure to download the larger English models download, rather than the default corenlp models download.

Comment: OK. This works - have had to download the 'larger' models mentioned on [this page](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP). However, even with 4 sentences, the local server times out (corenlp.run doesn't). Is there a way to increase such timeout?

Comment: -timeout 20000 did the job.

Comment: Yeah, something in the kbp annotator takes longer than it should. At some point I'll debug it myself, but if you beat me to it let me know!